# Configure Apache MPM worker module for 1000+ users at an instant

Tags: apache, load

I have youtube proxy site http://playit.pk, the issue is that whenever users increase over 500 at an instant the server gets really slow. I am using MPM Worker module and have tried several configs..

Current one is:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
ServerLimit          40
StartServers         10
MaxClients           2000
MinSpareThreads      25
MaxSpareThreads      75
ThreadsPerChild      50
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

other configurations are:

```
Timeout 20
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
```

Main server is only responsible for request handling, no streaming takes place here.

With the above configuration, still there is delay and apache shows around 1000 requests currently being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Use fastCGI

> FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
>
> FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 700